# vagrant up "msg": "failed to install XML_Util"

Tags: php

Getting below error while vagrant up. all other pear components are installed successfully except XML_Util

```
failed: [127.0.0.1] (item=XML_Util) => {
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "name": "XML_Util", 
            "state": "latest"
        }, 
        "module_name": "pear"
    }, 
    "item": "XML_Util", 
    "msg": "failed to install XML_Util"
}

RUNNING HANDLER [system : restart-cron] ****************************************
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/suji/Downloads/frame-test4/ansible/vagrant.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=9    changed=8    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.

Comment: 1- Edit your post make it more clear and readable. 
2- Attach the code causing the error 
3- Ask a question!

Comment: Did you follow this thread https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/issues/902 ?

Comment: which version of OS, php, apache you have .. can you give us your configuration details please.

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
PEAR Version: 1.10.3
PHP Version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
Zend Engine Version: 2.5.0
Running on: Linux bhushan-desktop 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64